# ios app refreshing functions only after double click of the home button

Tags: jquery, html, ios, cordova, refresh

I have a toggle switch in my phone gap application. When i turn it on, its function completes perfectly but all other parts of my app don't behave normally. If i double click home to show all the multitasking pages my app suddenly refreshes or kicks back into gear and everything is working again. What should i do? Thanks.

my toggle switch code is as followed, but i don't think the problem resides here, i think it must be with something about refreshing the app's state.

```
$('#slider').change(function() {
    var myswitch = $(this);
    var show     = myswitch[0].selectedIndex == 1 ? true:false;

    if(show) {
        for (var i = 0; i<uniqueIDarray.length; i++) {
            searchforSwap(i);

        }
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i<uniqueIDarray.length; i++) {
           searchforSwap(i); 

        }   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, my guess is that there is something running in your `deviceready` function that is causing the app to refresh correctly.  Once you locate what is actually refreshing the app correctly you will need to add it to your toggle code